# How does The Guardian's webpage overlay a checkerboard pattern on sections of the page that aren't fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here is an example.

[image]

I do not believe this is a WebKit (Blink now for Chrome) thing, so I am assuming it is a clever HTML/JavaScript/CSS thing. How is this done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a Chrome feature. I've seen it on a couple of pages.

Comment: Thanks to whoever added the image.

Comment: This is the only page I've ever seen it on.

Comment: My internet and computer are too fast to reproduce the effect, but I don't see anything in the source that would do that. I believe it's a chrome feature as well.

Comment: Is there anyway I can code that into my site, so other browsers see it?

Comment: Just a thought (I never tried it), but you could load the basic 4x4 matrix picture via CSS and tile, and then AJAX in the rest of the page.  It seems like a lot of work for a simple effect, though.

Comment: it's probably a chrome feature but a solution would be to create a very small page with a base64 encoded background checkboard pattern and then with ajax append the javascript and css.supported only by browsers that support base64images

Comment: If you see this it means the page is taking too long to load. I would not wish to replicate this effect as a user would associate it as a slow page. I'd personally optimise my page to load quicker. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/KWBMoDDUGUk/noIUfcyyl64J

Comment: I first noticed it after Chrome switched to the Blink rendering engine. (Chrome 28) It happens on all slow-loading or heavy pages that I scroll too fast.

Comment: I see. So, its a new thing with Blink.

Comment: @Mr.Shtuffs - It certainly seems to be the case. Well-aimed googling would probably tell me, but I'm yet to find myself curious enough. :grin:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is probably a new chrome thing..and noone wants this.. but as the answer is open and maybe someone wants to try to recreate this.. here is how it could be done.

1. create a html fileas small as possible
2. a 16x16 png converted to base64
3. load the rest of the css or or replace the existing
4. load the rest of the javascript

This is the smallest 16x16 png image converted to base64 i could get.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEX////MzMw46qqDAAAAEElEQVQImWNg+M+AFeEQBgB+vw/xfUUZkgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 window.document.head.appendChild(CSSLINK)
 window.document.head.appendChild(SCRIPTLINK)
}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but it's useless...

and here is a even smaller webp image :) only for chrome.

```
data:image/webp;base64,UklGRigAAABXRUJQVlA4IBwAAAAwAQCdASoQABAACMCWJaQAA3AA/u11j//aQAAA
```

ps.: at least i made a nice 16x16 (2 lines big) checkboard png in base64 ;)